# Python compare 3 text files and append to the original

Tags: python, csv, text

I would like to build a relationship between multiple text files using python to combine into one.  You can see that the 3-5 character are the same in both text files.  I want to get the third and fourth column for matches and add to the end of file one.  These are comma delimeted text files.

FILE 1

```
03**005**001,NAME,573.641235,0

03**022**001,NAME,-4.740656,58

03**023**001,NAME,-750,32

03**024**001,NAME,-1.937901,51

03**025**001,NAME,-1.327531,0
```

FILE 2

```
01**005**001,Name,1,0

01**022**001,Name,0,7

01**023**001,Name,0,21

01**024**001,Name,0,12

01**025**001,Name,0,0
```

Output.txt

```
03**005**001,NAME,573.641235,0,1,0

03**022**001,NAME,-4.740656,58,0,7
```

Comment: The below is doing what I want, I just need a little clarification on how to use it.  It is getting file one characters 2:5 and comparing it to file 2 characters 2:5.  Then I want to output the match with all columns from file 1 with file 2 column index 2 and 3 appended to the end of all columns from file one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
# compare.py
oneDict = {}
twoDict = {}

with open("file1.txt", "r") as one:
    for line in one:
        cells = line.split(",")
        oneDict[cells[0][2:5]] = cells

with open("file2.txt", "r") as two:
    for line in two:
        cells = line.split(",")
        twoDict[cells[0][2:5]] = cells

for match in set(oneDict.keys()).intersection(set(twoDict.keys())):
    oneRow = oneDict[match]
    twoRow = twoDict[match]
    print(oneDict[match][0],
          oneDict[match][1],
          oneDict[match][2],
          oneDict[match][3][:-1],
          twoDict[match][2],
          twoDict[match][3][:-1],
          sep=",")
```

And this command:

```
python compare.py > output.txt
```

Comment: So I am getting the first match, but it is not iterating through the rest of the records.  I cannot use the print statement indented it tells me that oneDict[match][1] Index out of range.  If I run without the indent it gives me the first record in the print statement.  If I just look at oneDict[match][0] it will iterate through all, but only giving me the ID.

Comment: Nevermind I had some blank spaces at the end of the file.